# Execute JS once all images are loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is my js class.

I need it to execute once all images are loaded, I understand I need to do this via:

```
$(window).load
```

But how would I incorporate this into my class?

```
this.mc = this.mc || {};

(function () {
    "use strict";
    var MyClass = function () {
        this.init();
    };
    p.init = function () {
        // Init
        this.ready();
    };
    mc.MyClass = MyClass;
}(window));

var myClass;

$(function () {
    myClass = new mc.MyClass();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
$(function () {
    myClass = new mc.MyClass();
});
```

with

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    myClass = new mc.MyClass();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if I get you.. but

```
window.onload = function() {
    myClass = new mc.MyClass();
};
```

should do.